# About the infinite open subcover of a open interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If there is an open interval $(0,1)$, then the infinite open cover of this open interval can be
$S=\{U_{i\in \mathbb N} |U_i=(\frac{1}{i}, 2)\} $.

I can intuitively know that the infinite subcovers in S can finally cover the open set$(0,1)$, but I don't know how to prove this formally.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Do you want to show it’s a cover ? That is not so hard.

Comment: Yes, basically I know it is an infinite cover, but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Let $x \in (0,1)$ be arbitrary and fixed then show that for some $i$ we have $ x\in U_i$.

Comment: So you mean, for any $x\in (0,1)$, there always exists i, such that $\frac{1}{i}$is less than $x$. Therefore, $S$ covers $(0,1)$. Is this correct？

Comment: Per the Archimedean principle, for any real number there is a natural number greater than it. If $x > 0$ and $n$ is a natural number greater than $\frac 1x$, then $$0 < \frac 1n < x$$